# Why use += to store a command's exit status in bash?

Tags: bash, exit-code

Recently I've come across this pattern in a Bash script:

```
function foo {
  declare -i status=0
  # command(s)
  (( status += $? ))
  return $status
```

Why would anyone use `+=` to save the exit status (instead of just `status=$?`) ?

Comment: This can be speculated, but for me the intention of author is to sum all the exit codes and then return this sum

Comment: this depends on the context. e.g. when `status=256`, `return $status` would be the same as `return 0`. so it does not always make sense to sum all exit codes. on the other hand, if all commands in the context returns 1 under some conditions and 0 otherwise, then `foo` can be used as a counter.

Answer (score 0):

The [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) limits [the exit status code for an application to `int`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html). This means that you can return a specific code for a specific error, for example:

> 0 - No failure
>   1 - IO Exception
>   2 - Runtime Exception
>   3 - HD head crash
>   etc.

But, what if your application crashed for multiple reasons? A way to convey this, is by returning a sum of exit codes that work a bit like [the 777 when dealing with permissions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/):

> 0 - No failure
>   1 - IO Exception
>   2 - Runtime Exception
>   4 - HD head crash

Now, if you can sum exceptions, and the sum will tell you what went wrong:

> 3 = 1 + 2 = IO Exception + Runtime Exception
>   5 = 1 + 4 = IO Exception + HD head crash
>   6 = 2 + 4 = Runtime Exception + HD head crash
>   7 = 1 + 2 + 4 = IO Exception + Runtime Exception + HD head crash

This could be a reason why they return a sum of exit codes.